# inoERP OneApp Server Log Errors when running

Tags: logging, erp

I am getting errors when I try to run the oneapp_windows file trying to get inoERP setup. The system.txt log shows the issues below....the C:/Files doesn't exist but the ./asset/...../prj/ files do. The last line says permission and I get the same errors when I run as admin. This is from; http://docs.inoerp.com/docs/app/start-server/

LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/prj/prj_revenue_doc_header_ev.js,prj/prj_generate_draft_revenue.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/ar/ar_transaction_header.js,shared/gl_journal_header_ev.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/prj/prj_budget_header_ev.js,prj/prj_generate_draft_revenue.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/ap/ap_payment_header.js,shared/gl_journal_header_ev.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/ar/ar_payment_header.js,shared/gl_journal_header_ev.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/inv/inv_transaction_doc_header.js,inv/gl_inv_transaction_doc_header.js,shared/gl_journal_header_ev.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/prj/prj_revenue_doc_header_ev.js,prj/prj_generate_draft_revenue.js,shared/gl_journal_header_ev.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/system/js/js.go:440:

Error in reading script function: open ./assets/js/ierp/ap/ap_transaction_header.js,shared/gl_journal_header_ev.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
LOG: 2022/08/11 11:14:58 C:/Files/GitHub/s-goRest/app/controller/controller.go:89: HTTP server ListenAndServe: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done any customization?
If you write your methods to be called before a GET/POST/PATCH/DELETE operation, you need to mention the same in the main.js file.

I usually run the original application on 8085 and customized applications on a separate port. So that I can easily check the expected behavior.

Just re-download the application and try it in a different port without any customization

Comment: I haven't done any customization yet, just trying to get the default applications to run.

Comment: I had my ports the same in the config file for application and database. Once I changed it to 8085, it ran. I do have some other errors now but I am going to make a new post to that.

Comment: Please accept the answer. I prefer the standard 3306 for MySQL and 8085 for Dev, and 8090 for Production.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download from github or forked it ?
Definitely something wrong with your file structures.
Make sure all the folders and files are available on your machine.
Below file specifies all the JavaScript paths
https://github.com/inoerp/inoERP/blob/master/assets/js/ierp/main.js

When you start the server, it checks if all the files are available or not.
You can remove all the paths for testing [by making let allMethods = {}] and run the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had my ports the same in the config file for application and database. Once I changed the application port to 8085, it ran.